Tailwind hover effect does not working in React Component
I have a React component called Buttons and as the name suggests, this component is used for all the buttons in my project. In order for this component to be completely dynamic, I decided to get the background color of the buttons from props(the background color is a tailwind class). Then I decided to put a hover class on the button so that when the mouse hovers over the button, the background color will increase by 100 units.
Button Component
export default function Button({ bg = "", children }) {

    let bgColor = bg.split("-")
    bgColor[2] = (+bgColor[2] + 100).toString()
    let hoverEffect = "hover:" + bgColor.join("-")

    return (
        <button className={`${bg} ${hoverEffect} flex items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-lg p-2 outline-none border-none transition-all cursor-pointer`}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}

Using Button Component
<Button bg={"bg-sky-500"}>
submit
</Button>

For this, I implemented the JavaScript logic of this program, but finally, when this class is added to the component, nothing happens. What is the problem?

When generating Dynamic Classes, we need to add those classes in safelist in the tailwind.config.js file.
An example demonstrating the use of safelist:


/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /bg-(.*)-(.*)/,
      variants: ['hover'],
    },
        ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}




Just verify the bg,hoverEffect  and make sure those are getting as you expected.
If it's not try splitting this line:
bgColor[2] = (+bgColor[2] + 100);
bgColor[2] = bgColor[2].toString()

There is also a logical mistake here what if the bg is something like this bg-blue-900 then your code will convert it to bg-blue-1000 in tailwind css  it's maximum is 900 i guess!
